# Ant - build requires Java 8+, fails despite having Java 11 installed

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, java, ant

I'm trying to build NetBeans 9 from sources on Raspbian using instructions from NetBeans site:
https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/nb90.html

I navigate to directory with unzipped sources and run `ant`, which produces error:

> BUILD FAILED
> /home/pi/Downloads/netbeans_sources/incubating-netbeans-java-9.0-source/nbbuild/build.xml:41 You need to run on JDK 8+ to build NetBeans; java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf

Raspbian Buster has Java 11 installed by default. I make sure to set `JAVA_HOME` using instructions from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users

I verify this by running `which java` which produces

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/bin/java

What is the cause of Ant build failing?

Comment: Do you have JDK or you just install JRE?

Comment: Yes, I have JDK